# iframe position from itself

Tags: javascript, iframe

how can I get iframe position using JS in the current iframe?

This code works in IE

```
var browser = navigator.appName;
if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  scrollX=self.screenLeft;  //works
  scrollY=self.screenTop;  //works strange
}
```

How to do it in Firefox?
`screenLeft`, `screenTop` - undefined
`screenX`, `screenY` -  the position of the parent window
`parent.frames[self.name].screenX` - the same result as screenX

Any idea, where is my iframe in FF? Thx.

Comment: Object topWindow.document is inaccesible :-(

Answer (score 1):

You could do this from within the iframe (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
var topWindow = window.top;
var leftTopPosition = findPos(topWindow.document.getElementById("iframe_id"));
```

You must specify the iframe's ID, or reference the iframe some other way.

Comment: Object topWindow.document is inaccesible :-(

Comment: I suppose this only works if iframe has the same origin as the parent document.